# sbt playframework publish submodules

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I have the following project structure:

```
myproject
  |
  +- app
  |
  +- conf
  |
  +- project
  |  |
  |  +- project
  |  |
  |  +- Build.scala (etc.)
  |
  +- modules
     |
     +- security
        |
        +- app
        |
        +- conf
```

Here is the snippet from my build file:

```
val security = PlayProject(
    appName + "-security", appVersion, path = file("modules/security")
)
```

If I try to do a `sbt publish` with a non snapshot version, sbt exits with following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: myproject-security#myproject-security_2.9.1;123
```

Of course it can't find the dependency in the repository. But how can I publish the submodules together with the main project?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I needed to aggregate the main project to achieve the desired result.
Like so:

```
...

lazy val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA)
.dependsOn(security)
.aggregate(security)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question does need more clarification to answer properly.  It would be nice to see more of your build file.

If your Play project is taking advantage of SBT sub-projects it should be compiled with the root project.  It looks like you are maybe declaring a dependency in your Build.scala for myproject-security.  Something like this maybe:

```
"myproject-security" %% "myproject-security" % "123"
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but it is hard to answer this question without seeing the complete build file.

Comment: sorry. I wasn't online for a longer time. Thanks for your answer. Found it out myself. Does my answer seem correct?